# Response object not rendering correctly in Response function

Tags: javascript, web

so I've got my head wrapped around this basic JAMstack premise, but I'm a bit confused about how the Response function works.
As far as I know, a fetch returns a Promise, which gets resolved as an object, which Response is supposed to correctly read/render into an HTML page, but when attempting to do so, I only render [Object object] to my browser.

When I try to play around with the response object itself (by console.log()), I get an object that looks like this:

```
{ cf: [accessor cf], webSocket: [accessor webSocket], url: [accessor url], redirected: [accessor redirected], ok: [accessor ok], … }
```

How exactly are we supposed to render a response object into a valid HTML page?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured this out.
fetch() returns a response object (within a Promise), which can be manipulated with various functions, all of which are asynchronous.
To return the HTML, simply use the text() function, but it is also asynchronous (it returns a Promise), so using an await before doing so will give you the desired HTML (if that's what you want).

Similarly, if you're building an API instead, you can just retrieve JSON from the response object as well.

It's all here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response